# Excel services API for office 365

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, office-web-apps, office-365-develop-tool

I have added a excel workbook to a document library in office 365.

1. Office 365 you cannot add a Trusted Location for excel Services.
2. I have enabled SharePoint enterprise services

When I try open the

```
link https://sites/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/Shared%20Documents/TS.xls/model?$format=workbook
```

I get a 401 error.

Am I missing something or is it not possible to use excel services API in Office 365.